# Can someone explain how positional arguments in the sort function(key parameter) work?

Tags: python, function

Python Version:3.8

What I am trying to do:I am trying to write this function that takes a string of words as an input(called sentence) where each word has one number, splits it into a list at each whitespace, loops through every letter in every element, and then returns the number it finds. We then sort the lst variable which has the words of the sentence input as its elements based on the numbers we got.
When I run this code I wrote to execute the above steps:

```
def order(sentence):
    # list of the words in sentence
    lst=sentence.split(' ')
    # nested function that is used as the key argument in the sort method
    def sort_func():
        for i in sentence:
            for j in i:
                if j.isdigit():
                    return j
    # sorting the list
    lst.sort(key=sort_func)
    # returning a string which has the words sorted according to the number we found in each one
    return ' '.join(lst)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"), "Thi1s is2 3a T4est")
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 12, in order
    lst.sort(key=sort_func)
TypeError: sort_func() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Now if i replace this line:

```
def sort_func()
```

by this:

```
def sort_func(sentence)
```

It works and the error is gone.

My question is why is that. I am not convinced. What does positional argument have to do with the code I wrote? I researched how nested functions work to see where the problem was and read about positional arguments, but this still doesn't make sense to me. A detailed explanation of why I got this error is what I want.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with nested functions. `def sort_func():` defines a function that takes zero arguments, but `key=` expects a function that takes one argument. The error is simply due to that mismatch. The behavior would be identical if `sort_func` were a top-level, un-nested function like `order`.

`def sort_func(sentence):` fixed it because now `sort_func` accepts a single argument, which means it's usable as a `key` function.

Comment: I read some documentation for the sort method here are the links: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html   ,  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort Whether or not this was mentioned, maybe I didn't see it, maybe I was browsing too fast i appreciate the response and I'm sorry for the confusing title. Your right it doesn't have to do with nested functions. Its just that i didn't know what was the problem. I'll try and edit the question. If you have any suggestions on that I would appreciate it too XD. I Don't want to confuse people. Thanks for the response

Comment: @Sleepy No problem. And I only put that first sentence in because I believed nested functions were a red herring here that was confusing matters.